# Variable PHP download-header file name?

Tags: php, html, header, save

What's the proper syntax for this?

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="{$_SESSION['name']} . '.txt');
```

This file works, though only properly when "view source" (HTML not formatted but contains correct line breaks).

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html");
session_start();
    if(file_exists("chat") && filesize("chat") > 0){
        $handle = fopen("chat", "r");
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize("chat"));
        fclose($handle);
        ob_start();
$download = strip_tags($contents, '<br>');
$processed = preg_replace('#<br\s*/?>#i', "\n", $download);
echo $processed;
$var = ob_get_clean();
echo $var;
    }
?>
```

The `$_SESSION['name']` variable is something like `guest_158512` and if you view the source of the page I'm trying to save, it has all the line breaks. How do I save the current page as `guest_158512.txt` with the proper syntax?

Comment: `filename="{$_SESSION['name']} . '.txt'` Do you want to close `"`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem here is that you've tried to use single quotes. Single quotes do not interpolate variables in PHP.

You have also failed to properly terminate the string, probably due to putting more single quotes inside it. Try:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$_SESSION['name'].'.txt"');
```

Kolink also [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9246928/383402) that you should use `Content-Type: text/plain` to serve plain-text non-HTML files.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who posted. The file is now named properly, and saves correctly. If you open the file with notepad, none of the lines are saved. BUT if you open with MS Word, DreamWeaver, or any other "application" the lines stay there. I'm not sure how to solve that. EDIT: \r\n instead of \n ?

Comment: @mesh Unix line endings (`\n`) are not handled by Notepad, which expects Windows line endings (`\r\n`).

Comment: Got that working already on my own, but it's good do have it documented here for future users.

Answer (score 2):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$_SESSION['name'].".txt\"");
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

For future reference, using a proper code editor such as Notepad++ would show you that your quotes are badly mismatched.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. With single quotes, you may do the following:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $_SESSION['name'] . '.txt"');
```

Comment: It is better to leave the quotes (coupled, of course) for the case of the filename with spaces. Just in case :)